# comparative of the adjective "grave"

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

I had written

> The effect of traumatic experience may be graver if...

and the editor has corrected it to

> The effect of traumatic experience may be more grave if...

Surely grave conforms to the regular rules for comparatives? Am I missing something? (I note that graver is also a tool for making engravings - but that's irrelevant.)

Comment: The [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grave1_2) gives "grave, graver, gravest". [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grave) also gives "comparative graver, superlative gravest." If the topic was bereavement, perhaps the editor would avoid that word altogether and use "more serious".

Comment: Editors do more than correct grammar. It may be that your editor thinks it is better style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grave1_2) gives "grave, graver, gravest". [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grave) also gives "comparative graver, superlative gravest." If the topic was bereavement, perhaps the editor would avoid that word altogether and use "more serious".

<sup><sup>Credit: [**Weather Vane**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508342/comparative-of-the-adjective-grave#comment1231470_508342)</sup></sup>